# Permanently store pig.jar on hdfs

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, hdfs

Whenever I run a pig script through the java PigServer interface, a fresh copy of pig-XXX.jar is copied to my remote hdfs cluster. Is there a way to avoid this and instead have the pig.jar permanently stored on my cluster?